# Is there a way to convert a multi_index into a int string / list / array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, array-indexing

I want to change a value of given array in numpy to a multiplication of other elements of the array. Therefore I want to extract the multi_index and manipulate it so that I can identify the position and use it. (e.g. nditer through all elements and always do 'current position in array = next position +position above in array'

I tried to call a function with the multi_index of the current position and want said function to take it and e.g. increase it by one position. (<0 , 1> ---> <0 , 2> while <0 , n> n>=length otherwise <0 , 1> ---> <1 , 0>)

```py
import numpy as np;

def fill(multi_index):
    "This will get the new value of the current iteration value judgeing from its index"
    return a[(multi_index + <0,1>) + (multi_index + <0,-1>) + (multi_index + <1,0>) + (multi_index + <-1,0>)]

#a = np.random.uniform(0, 100, size=(100, 100))
a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)

it = np.nditer(a, flags=['multi_index'], op_flags=['readwrite'])
while not it.finished:
    it[0] = fill(it.multi_index)
    print(it[0])
    it.iternext()

"""for x in np.nditer(a, flags=['multi_index'], op_flags=['readwrite']):

    print(x)"""
```

I don't understand how to extract the actual "coordinates" from the multi_index. I am kinda new to python so please try to explain it thoroughly if possible. Thanks.

**Edit**: Before I only coded on C++ and a bit Java, so I used to mainly using arrays (in c++ it would be somthing like this:

```cpp
int main() { 
  int a[100][100];
  for (int i=1, i<=a.length-1, i++) { 
    for (int j=1, i<=a.width-1, j++) { 
      a[i][j] = 1/4 (a[i][j+1]+a[i][j-1]+a[i+1][j]+a[i-1][j]);
    } 
  } 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stay away from `nditer`, especially if you are beginner.  It does not improve iteration speed.  Show with plain indexed for loops what you are trying to do.

Comment: Providing a sample input and preferred output would help as well

Comment: Normally the input would be a 100x100 array with random values and in various steps of iterations each element in the array would be set to 1/4 of the neighboring elements. After 1000 iterations or so, the finished array will be printed out. In order to change the values of an element to a product of its neighboring elements I need to extracts its "coordinates"and (in the seperate funtions fill) get the new value through simple multiplications. At the moment there is nothing in the fill-function yet.

Comment: In for loops:  

```python
for x in for x in np.nditer(a, flags=['multi_index'], op_flags=['readwrite']:
    a[x] = 1/4 ( a[mutil_index + <0,1>] + a[mutil_index + <0, -1>] + a[mutil_index + <1,1>] + a[mutil_index + <-1,-1>] )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [152]: a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)                                                                  
In [153]: a                                                                                              
Out[153]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

Let's run your `nditer` and look at its values:

```
In [157]: it = np.nditer(a, flags=['multi_index'], op_flags=['readwrite'])                               
In [158]: while not it.finished: 
     ...:     print(it.multi_index, a[it.multi_index], it[0], type(it[0])) 
     ...:     it.iternext() 
     ...:                                                                                                
(0, 0) 0 0 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(0, 1) 1 1 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(0, 2) 2 2 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(1, 0) 3 3 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(1, 1) 4 4 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(1, 2) 5 5 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

At each iteration `multiindex` is a tuple of the `i,j` indices.  `a[it.multiindex]` then selects that item from the array.  But `it[0]` is also that item, but wrapped as a 0d array.  If you aren't comfortable with the idea of a 0d array (shape `()`) then `nditer` is not the tool for you (at this time).

If you just want the sequential indexing tuples, `ndindex` works just as well:

```
In [162]: list(np.ndindex(a.shape))                                                                      
Out[162]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
```

(in fact, `np.lib.index_tricks.py` shows that `ndindex` uses the `nditer` multiindex.  `nditer` isn't commonly used in `numpy` Python level code.)

Or to get indices plus value:

```
In [177]: list(np.ndenumerate(a))                                                                        
Out[177]: [((0, 0), 0), ((0, 1), 1), ((0, 2), 2), ((1, 0), 3), ((1, 1), 4), ((1, 2), 5)]
```

Just values in flat order:

```
In [178]: a.ravel()                                                                                      
Out[178]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

BUT, in `numpy` we prefer not to iterate at all.  Instead we try to write code that works with the whole array, using the fast compiled `numpy` methods.  Iteration on arrays is slow, slower than iteration on lists.

===

Looks like your iteration, in a somewhat stylized sense, is:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
         a[i,j] = ( a[i,j+1] + a[i,j-1] + a[i+1,j] + a[i-1,j] )/4
```

There some details to worry about.  What about the edges, where `j+/-1` is out of bounds?  And is this calculation sequential, so that `a[i,j]` depends on the changes just made to `a[i,j-1]`; or is it buffered?

In general sequential, iterative calculations on an array like this are a bad fit for `numpy`.

On the other hand, buffered calculations can be nicely done with whole-array slices

```
x[1:-1, 1:-1] = (x[:,:-1]+x[:,1:]+x[:-1,:]+x[1:,:])/4
```

There are also, in `scipy` some convolution functions that perform calculations on moving windows.

Comment: Normally the input would be a 100x100 array with random values and in various steps of iterations each element in the array would be set to 1/4 of the neighboring elements. After 1000 iterations or so, the finished array will be printed out. In order to change the values of an element to a product of its neighboring elements I need to extracts its "coordinates"and (in the seperate funtions fill) get the new value through simple multiplications. At the moment there is nothing in the fill-function yet.

I don't particularly care about them being 0d-arrays ( I suppose simple scalars? )

Comment: Perhaps there is a fast compiled numpy method for these kinds of iterations, but this was the best way I could find in the moment. Before I only coded on C++ and a bit Java, so I used to mainly using arrays (in c++ it would be like this: 
int main() {
for (int i=1, i<=a.length-1, i++) {
  for (int j=1, i<=a.width-1, j++) {
    a[i][j] = 1/4 (a[i][j+1]+a[i][j-1]+a[i+1][j]+a[i-1][j]);
}
}
return 0;
}

Comment: I think you will be badly disappointed with the speed of this kind of iteration in `numpy`.

Comment: That actually looks really nice, can you explain how the last code bit works precicely? I also decided that I might have better calculation times in c++ and have a new question concerning this topic.

Comment: Make a simple 1d array (e.g. `np.arange(12)`) and try this pair wise difference calculation, `arr[1:]-arr[:-1]`.  That should give you a feel for what is going on.